# Parsing a URL with urlparse.parse_qs not working

Tags: python

```
query_str = parse_qs(response)
```

returns a null dict where

```
response ={"access_token":"<edited>","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":4502}
```

My code was working fine until a few days ago. I did not make any changes. parse_qs suddenly stopped working properly and I do not know why. Can I use any other url parse to get the same results?

Comment: `response` is a dict? Or a string that looks like a dict? Either way, `parse_qs` can't parse either of those.

Comment: Don't post your access_token to a public place...

Comment: And generate a new access token immediately.

Comment: `response` is clearly not a query string anymore. If it's a dict, surely you already have what you need? If it's a string, use `json.loads`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. I'll try using json.loads. Thanks for editing my access token as well.